# Going mad with infinite loop and RewriteCond, need help

Tags: .htaccess, loops, infinite-loop, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect users to my home page if they enter any URL **not starting with** 'en' or 'fr'. I've spent hours trying to make this work but this proves too tough for my fragile newbie brain. Currently, if I try to go to

```
http://mysite.com/fr/produits/
```

Firefox tells me that the redirect will never complete.

Here's what I want:

```
http://mysite.com/en/whatever/ ==> rewrite as /whatever/index.php?lang=en
http://mysite.com/fr/whatever/ ==> rewrite as /whatever/index.php?lang=fr

http://mysite.com/jp/whatever/ ==> 301 redirect to /fr/accueil/ 
http://mysite.com/whatever/ ==> 301 redirect to /fr/accueil/
```

Here's my current htaccess. See inline comments for details.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Require no www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301]

# Redirect from root to /fr/accueil/, the URL for the default home page
RewriteRule ^/$ http://mysite.com/fr/accueil/ [NC,R=302]

# Rewrite language path fragment (/fr or /en) as a parameter 
RewriteRule ^fr/accueil/$ /accueil/index.php?lang=fr [QSA,NC] 
RewriteRule ^en/home/$ /accueil/index.php?lang=en [QSA,NC] 
RewriteRule ^fr/produits/$ /produits/index.php?lang=fr [QSA,NC] 
RewriteRule ^en/products/$ /produits/index.php?lang=en [QSA,NC] 

# I'm aware that the rules in this htaccess are re-examined each
# time a rewrite is issued. So the 'fr/accueil/' I'm redirecting to
# will itself be rewritten as /accueil/index.php?lang=fr. That is
# why I'm providing 3 conditions:
# If URI does not start with 'en' AND
# If URI does not start with 'fr' AND
# If QUERY_STRING is not exactly 'lang'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^en/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^fr/.*$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^lang$
RewriteRule ^.*$ fr/accueil/ [NC,R=301]
```

Please put me out of my misery. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the last line

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ fr/accueil/ [NC,R=301]
```

With

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ fr/accueil/ [NCL,R=301]
```

Comment: Sorry, no change (I assumed you meant [NC,L,R=301])